# bunsen vs meker for best sterile field

Tags: microbiology, homework, lab-techniques, mycology, materials

I need one bunsen and i have a friend that sells me a bunsen-meker burner.

I see that bunsen-meker burners have more flame diameter, so should have more diameter of sterile field, but i dont know XD

Is good for sterile field? or i should buy a typical bunsen?

thanks.

Comment: Can you maybe explain what you plan to work on?

Comment: I need to prepare culture media to inoculate with spores of my mushrooms. Isolate the mycelium and inoculate liquid media for later inoculation in solid media for medium-scale production.      
Until now I used a homemade still an air (SAB), with good results, but uncomfortable and unpredictable.
Now I want to buy a lighter to have a sterile field as large as possible, so I would like to know if the bunsen-meker that I have available to buy is correct or do I need a common bunsen burner, which I It would be more expensive as it is not second hand (the meker is brand new).

Comment: Bunsen was a person. Give him a capital in your title at least, even if you have an aversion to titular norms.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in flame diameter between a Bunsen and Meker (or Fisher) burner really isn't that much, so I'm not sure how much larger the sterile field would be. On the other hand, Fisher burners can be tuned to be much hotter than standard Bunsen burners, so that may impact the size of the field as well. But, at the same time, they use more fuel, so you have to think of that as an additional cost.

If you're just sterilizing inoculating needles/loops, flask necks, etc., a Bunsen is perfectly fine. However, if you're trying to create a larger "sterile" field, there are too many variables to make a definitive recommendation. Are you setting up in an area with relatively little airflow, or are there cross-breezes? How large of a field do you actually need - what is the area where you'll be working with open containers of sterile media?

All in all, to be safest, you'd probably want the Fisher burner, but I don't know what the cost differential is and what your budget is. If you're careful with media manipulation and have a good still area to work in, a Bunsen should be fine, though.

Comment: thanks! This info is so useful!

Comment: @JaumeEscaleCamps glad to help. If this answer [addressed your problem](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.